# Angular restAPI call to java returns 400 error

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate

I am trying to call the hibernate restapi through the angularjs but it returns 400 error , but when I am making the call through post man it returns the value,
my code as follwos

**java code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public static Response getCustomerDetails(@RequestParam("userId")Long userId, 
                                              @RequestParam("itemId")ArrayList<Long> itemId)  throws AViewException
{
    customerDetails=new object({"customerName":xxx});
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(customerDetails).build();
}
```

**angularjs**

```
var itemId=[374,375,376,377];
$scope.selected ={
            userId:$rootScope.user.userId,
            itemId:itemId
        };
console.log($scope.selected);       
$http({ method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://10.3.2.204:8080/aview/sample.html',                        
    headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            'Accept': '*/*'},                       
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.selected)

})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{   
    console.log(data);
     $scope.data = data;
     console.log($scope.data);

})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
{
    alert("error"); 
    console.log(data);                                  
});
```

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
```

Comment: Try:
$http({ method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://10.3.2.204:8080/aview/sample.html',                        
    headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
            'Content-Type': undefined,
    data: $scope.selected

})

Comment: Dont stringify the data - scope.selected. Also, your Spring RequestParameter for items is an arraylist, and you are not sending it.. Instead you are sending itemId. Is this what you intended.

Comment: @YogeshPatil sorry, I have mistakenly posted the code, its not `items` its `itemId` only, now I have changed the code and I tried without stringify the data even Im getting the same error

Comment: @chenop its not working, instead it giving the cors error, even I have opened the cors request already. and there was few mistake like extra `;` and missing `}` i changed those also even I get the error `$http({ method: 'POST', url: 'http://10.3.2.204:8080/aview/sample.html';, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0', 'Content-Type': undefined, data: $scope.selected }}) `